# WebSphere MQ 7.5.0. Command and definition mapping

Tags: mapping, ibm-mq, definition

Some IBM websphere commands match particular object definition atrribute names, how do I know which attribute belongs to which particular IBM websphere command?
I want to map IBM WebSphere MQ 7.5.0 command to particular definition attribute.
For example for Local Queue:

```
+-----------------+------------------+
|   command name  |  definition name |
+-----------------+------------------+
|   MQCA_Q_NAME   |     "QLOCAL"     |
|   MQCA_Q_DESC   |     "DESCR"      |
+-----------------+------------------+
```

That is a mapping for local queue, however, the problem is that there are a lot of attributes to map and I'm just keep guessing which attribute belogs to particular definition element. I used this page  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q087810_.htm?lang=en to figure out what particular element means.

Is there any table where I could find MQ commands and definitions mappings or is there any more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct tabular MQSC <-> PCF documentation I'm afraid... Read this discussion for some background

http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=328375&sid=70185e9883087b72ab1eabbcb99ae6ff